# Problem understanding a GRE quantitative question

Tags: algebra-precalculus

[image]

I am confused about the question being asked here. Given the range is 17cm and one measurement is 49.5 which could be the largest measurement or not. So if I take 49.5-17=32.5, then the least value could be 32.5 or lower. Since the question asks about which value **could be** one of the 200 measurements, all the four options are possible.

However, the answer is C,D, which implies that 49.5 is the maximum value.

Comment: How do you conclude “32.5 or lower” when you know the range is $17$? The farthest away from $49.5$ possible is $32.5$ or $66.5$ (depending on $49.5$ being max or min)

Comment: $49.5 - 32 = 17.5 \gt 17$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The range of $200$ measurements is $= 17$ centimeters

If $49.5$ is the lowest measurement in the set, then the highest measurement in the set of measurement $= 49.5 +$ range $= 49.5 + 17 = 66.5$ centimeters

If $49.5$ is the highest measurement in the set, then the lowest measurement in the set of measurement $= 49.5 -$ range $= 49.5 - 17 = 32.5$ centimeters

In the second case we have two values that lie between $32.5$ centimeters and $49.5$ centimeters.